# adding media_image attribute sql catalog

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute, media-images

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,'expert_author_image',
    array (
        'group'             => 'Expert recommandation',
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'label'             => 'Expert author image',
        'input'             => 'media_image',
        'is_configurable'   => 1,
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'           => true,
        'default'           => '',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => '',
        'sort'              => '6'
    )
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

it add image to images folder where product image is but not to seperate group